# VirtualTreeView copy tree with data

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

How to copy all nodes from one VirtualTreeView to another?
I tried to use CopyTo-function, but the Data was empty, why?
Data contains reference to record (as usual).

I've also tried to use the `OnNodeCopying` event as @Cosmin Prund suggested in his now deleted answer this way, but it crashes:

```
procedure TDataBaseForm.SourceTreeViewNodeCopying(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; 
  Node, Target: PVirtualNode; var Allowed: Boolean); 
var 
  SourceNodeData, DestNodeData: PNodeDataForCompare; 
begin 
  SourceNodeData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node); 
  DestNodeData := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(Target); 
  if Assigned(SourceNodeData) then 
  begin 
    DestNodeData^ := SourceNodeData^; 
  end; 
  Allowed := true; 
end;
```

Comment: How can I allow you to include code in my question? I'm new in stackoverflow.

Comment: It was just a rhetorical note :-) I've included the code from your comment by the @Cosmin's (now deleted answer), but please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14910000/edit) and include the exact error message you're getting, when you use that code. And, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: If you say "it crashes", then all I can say is: "well, fix it!". If you tell us what exception occurs, what the error message is, and on which line it occurs, we might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: The way `CopyTo` works is a bit troublesome: all the nodes to be copied are first streamed to an in-memory stream, and then re-created. While the nodes are re-created the `OnNodeCopying` is called, but with useless parameters: The `Node` is the newly created node, and the `Target` is the `Target` node that was passed to `CopyTo()`. That's why I deleted my answer, it's a bad "lead" unfortunately. You'd need the original node + the new node to be able to copy data, but you get the new node and the node that was used as the Target.

Comment: An other idea would be to implement the `OnSaveNode` and `OnLoadNode` to save/read the nodes to the stream used by VirtualTreeView. I think those two would make VT's copying to work, but I don't have time to test and I don't want to provide an other partial answer that might not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've dug a bit deeper into how the `CopyTo()` works. All the nodes to be copied are first saved to a stream, next the nodes from the stream are re-created on the target VirtualTree. The user node data needs to be copied into that stream, or else it will not be available when re-creating the nodes in the target VirtualTree.

The events that handle streaming user data are:

- OnSaveNode
- OnLoadNode

It makes sense for the VirtualTree to make use of those methods, and as a consequence makes sense to use the stream as an intermediary object. The VirtualTree also allows saving the tree to a file and copy-pasting nodes to and from clipboard. All those methods need to somehow copy the user's "payload"! After implementing those events the `CopyTo` method worked fine, so did saving the the content of the first tree to disk and re-loading it into the second tree. I also tested copy-pasting and it worked fine.

Here's my implementation of the `OnSaveNode` and `OnLoadNode`. Copy-pasting my methods will most likely not work for you, because it depends on the kind of data you put in the node payload. In my example I placed records (not pointers-to-records) made up of just one Integer: those records can safely be streamed to disk and reloaded, they're not managed types, they're simple value types. If you're placing pointers into the records (reference-to-records as you called them) you can still use this and it will work, but you'd be copying POINTERS: You don't get new records, they're the same records; you obviously can't save the Tree to a file, restart the program and reload from disk.

```
procedure TForm6.VT1SaveNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Stream: TStream);
begin
  Stream.Write(Sender.GetNodeData(Node)^, (Sender as TVirtualStringTree).NodeDataSize);
end;

procedure TForm6.VT2GetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
begin
  CellText := IntToStr(PNodeDataForCompare(VT1.GetNodeData(Node)).Payload);
end;
```

One final note: For your scenario you'll need the `OnSaveNode` implemented on the Source tree and the `OnLoadNode` implemented on the Target tree; I implemented them on both using the same code.

Comment: I've tried to use your code, but it is not work for me (node data is empty). I also use simple value types (strings and integer values). Can you attach your project-files? I will try to compare it with my code.

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll paste-bin the whole test project.

Comment: Paste bin for [Unit6.pas](http://pastebin.com/DxpGPyBJ) and [Unit6.dfm](http://pastebin.com/Q8h3sRir); You'll see every test I made, including CopyTo, Copy-Paste, Save to file, Reload from file.

Answer (score 0):

```
unit VirtualTrees;

...

function TBaseVirtualTree.CopyTo(Source, Target: PVirtualNode; Mode: TVTNodeAttachMode; ChildrenOnly: Boolean): PVirtualNode;

...

        Result := TargetTree.MakeNewNode;
        InternalConnectNode(Result, Target, TargetTree, Mode);
        TargetTree.InternalAddFromStream(Stream, VTTreeStreamVersion, Result);
        if not DoNodeCopying(Result, Source {Target}) then //        <=======
        begin
          TargetTree.DeleteNode(Result);
          Result := nil;
        end
```

...